# Can't reset a listview after filtering

Tags: java, android, filter

I currently have a list view that is populated in my 'onCreate' i have an edit text that is filtering by a constraint passed to my 'onTextChanged' method, this is then sent to a 'getChanges' method in my database handler class and using an LIKE statement it is filtered. At the moment when I have deleted the string search from my edittext (i.e it is blank) I want all of the contants to redisplay. Currently I cannot get it to do this, the data shown just shows the last filtered data.

This is my Filter:

```
    searchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    searchedListResults.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    searchName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    getCons = new DBHandler(this, null, null);
    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            getCons.open();
            return getCons.getChanges(constraint.toString());
        }
    });
```

And this is the method in my database handler class, at first I thought it was because I was closing the cursor in my 'IF' but this dosent seem to make a difference.

```
public Cursor getChanges(String constraintPassed) {

        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_TEL, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COMMENTS};
        Cursor c = null;
         if(constraintPassed == "" || constraintPassed.length() == 0)
         {
             c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC", null); 
             c.close();

         }

         else
         {

            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + " LIKE'" + constraintPassed + "%'", null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC", null);

         }

        if( c != null)
            {
                c.moveToFirst();
                return c;

            }
        return null;
    }


    }
```

Comment: `constraintPassed == ""`. Java 101, String comparison

Comment: the fact that you are closing the cursor certainly doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You should use this after the filtration :

```
((EfficientAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where `EfficientAdapter` is your Adapter class.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

```
cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

with

```
yourclassname.this.cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

in your `onTextChanged` method.

Comment: no. If this could solve the error, the error would be a compilation error, not a runtime error.